# Image Picker is returning NIL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am getting a crash saying that my assignment is nil, but the guard should cover that.

```
extension viewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            print("Image not found!")
            return
        }
        imageTaken.image = selectedImage <=== Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    }
}
```

Doing a po in the debugger I get the following value

```
(lldb) po selectedImage <UIImage:0x281f058c0 anonymous {3024, 4032}>
```

Which is obviously not nil so am a bit confused.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your image view is nil, not the image

Comment: Check wether you have proper outlets for imageTaken view. This is nil

Comment: Figured it out.. the NIL was on the left side of the equal sign not the right side.